# Translate `thread.start_new_thread(...)` to the new threading API

Tags: python, multithreading

When I use the old Python `thread` API everything works fine:

```
thread.start_new_thread(main_func, args, kwargs)
```

But if I try to use the new [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects) API the process, which runs the thread hangs when it should exit itself with `sys.exit(3)`:

```
threading.Thread(target=main_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()
```

How can I translate the code to the new threading API?

You can see this example in [context](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py#L89).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is due to the fact that `thread.start_new_thread` creates a thread in `daemon` mode while `threading.Thread` creates a thread in `non-daemon` mode.
To start `threading.Thread` in daemon mode, you need to use `.setDaemon` method:

```
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=main_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
my_thread.setDaemon(True)
my_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

The program will exit when all non-daemon threads have exited. You can make your secondary `Thread` daemonic by setting its `daemon` property to `True`.

Alternatively you can replace your call to `sys.exit` with `os._exit`.